# How to create a masked password box in a Python FMX GUI app?

Tags: python, user-interface, passwords, firemonkey

I'm making an app using [DelphiFMX GUI library for Python](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python). I need to have a component where I can enter a password and have that password masked. Sure I can use an `Edit` component, but then the password is in plain text and not masked.

How do I mask a password in an Edit component or is there a component specifically for passwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `Edit` component is actually the correct way. There's a `Password` boolean property that you simply need to set to `True` and it'll work then:

```
self.myPasswordBox.Password = True
```

[image: Python GUI Password Box]

Here's the full code I used to create the Edit:

```
self.myPasswordBox = Edit(self)
self.myPasswordBox.Parent = self
self.myPasswordBox.Align = "Center"
self.myPasswordBox.Width = 250
self.myPasswordBox.Password = True # Make it a password box that is masked
```